# Angular 7 and angular material how to get the selected option text of mat-select instead of its value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I need to get the selected text of  material drop down list `<mat-select>` instead of its value:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fr">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Family Rel. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Family Relation</mat-label>
              <mat-select #familyRelation (selectionChange)="onChange(element, i, 'hh')" id="family_relation"
                formControlName="fr" placeholder="Family Relation">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id">
                  {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

And here is how I am trying to do:

```
@ViewChild('familyRelation') familyRel: ElementRef;
```

And on change selection of the drop list:

```
onChange(data, i, type) {
    let c = this.familyRel.nativeElement.innerText;
    console.log(c)
}
```

I had the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
>       at

And when I remove `innerText`, the consoled value is:

> undefined

What I need as you can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-gk6sky), if I chosed `Parent`, I want to get `Parent` into a variable and not `1` which is its `id`.

Please note that `element`, `i` and `hh` in `(selectionChange)=onChange(element,...)` are used later in the function, so forget about it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated the code, and added `click` event on the `options`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-w89kwc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Added one function

```
  getInnerText(innerText){
    console.log(innerText)
  }
```

Added click event in view

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id" (click)="getInnerText(familyRelation.family_relation_type)">
    {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Are you sure ? It gave me `innerText does not exists` error even on stackblitz

Comment: Have you checked on this link `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-w89kwc?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts`

Comment: Look what is happening. This drop list is a form control array. When I change the selected option, it gave me the old selected option.

Comment: If I'm checking on the link, and changing the values, I'm getting the exact value in the console which is selected by me

Comment: You must be checking jkubm answer. the both issue exists in that link

Comment: Wait. I updated the stackblitz, check it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-wuavbe

Comment: Okay, as you are checking in the onChange method of mat. Actually, the onChange runs before the onClick of option thats why you are getting the previous value. Do you still need onchage of mat-select?

Comment: Yes. As I want to run `getData()`. If both can be run through `onClick` it is okay with that, but how to do it ?

Comment: you can do any stuff in getInnerText() method, which you were doing in onChange. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dp8yzk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: It will work on all drop down lists ? because I have a form array of this drop list for each user? let me try it.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for being late to the party. I'm really horrified of reading all answers above...

The solution is much easier and direct than any of the proposed answers, as the select component just passes the selected model as part of the `selectionChange` argument.

But first, some corrections to your example. You've declared an interface, so USE IT:

```
export interface FamilyRelation {
    id: number;
    type: string;
}
```

So, in your constructor:

```
 constructor() {
    this.familyRelationArray=[
    {
      id: 1,
      type: 'Parent'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      type: 'Sister'
    }
  ]
}
```

and not what you put in your StackBlitz... Then your view will become this:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="onChange($event)" id="family_relation" placeholder="Family Relation">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="familyRelation.id">
        {{familyRelation.type}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**No need for the (click) handler for every mat-option, since it isn't necessary and could lead to performance issues if you have a lot of options. Now, on the controller:**

```
onChange(ev: any) {
   let optionText = ev.source.selected.viewValue;
   console.log(optionText);
}
```

or, if you prefer, the typed variant:

```
onChange(ev: MatSelectChange) {
   let optionText = (ev.source.selected as MatOption).viewValue;  //use .value if you want to get the key of Option
   console.log(optionText);
}
```

but don't forget the imports...

```
import { MatSelectChange } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatOption } from '@angular/material/core';
```

Comment: This should be the accepted anwer. Includes typings, also the simplest answer I have seen of a _lot_ of answers. One minor improvement, you can simplify the import statements into just 1: `import {MatSelectChange, MatOption} from '@angular/material';`

Comment: Is there a way to get the selected object itself, not its value or its label ? (by using any listener method, not binding)

Answer (score 4):

You can add index to loop with mat-option then pass it to onChange() method and it will allow you to get the selected element from array.

```
<mat-select #familyRelation (selectionChange)="onChange($event.value, element, i, 'hh')" id="family_relation" placeholder="Family Relation">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray; let i=index" [value]="i">
        {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```
 onChange(index, data, i, type) {
    console.log(this.familyRelationArray[index].family_relation_type);
}
```

Here you have update code: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-gk6sky)

Comment: It worked. Is it a long time solution or just temporary ?

Comment: It worked but check the link, it is reading the previous value when `getData()` is fired: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-wuavbe

Comment: As far as I can see in your example, the `mat-option` index is not accessible on `mat-select` level.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `compareWith`

```
 <mat-select #familyRelation [compareWith]="compareFn" id="family_relation"  formControlName="fr" placeholder="Family Relation">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id">
          {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>


compareFn(data1 , data2){

}
```

`compareWith` listen to the 'change' event because 'input' events aren't fired for selects in Firefox. [DOC](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor).

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a bit late, but answers have inspired me a bit, here is an idea:

```
export interface IFamilyGroup{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

familyGroup: IFamilyGroup[];

getSelectOption( family: IFamilyGroup ): void {
    console.log(family);
}

<mat-select (selectionChange)="getSelectOption( familyGroup[$event.value] )">
  <mat-option>none</mat-option>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let family of familyGroup; let i = index"
    value="{{i}}">
        {{ family.name }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you cannot use formControlName, because mat-option uses index as value, so if you want to match formgroup, you can change it to this:

```
// this is formgroup data model
export interface IFamilyGroup{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    address: string;
}

export interface IFormGroupDataForm{
    family: FormControl;
    whatever1?: FormControl;
    whatever2?: FormControl;
}


dataForm: FormGroup;
family = new FormControl();

familyGroup: IFamilyGroup[];

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initFormGroup();
}

private initFormGroup() {
    dataForm = this.fromFormGroupModel({
      family: this.family
      // any you need...
    });
}

private fromFormGroupModel( model: IFormGroupDataForm ): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group(model);
}


getSelectOption( family: IFamilyGroup ): void {
    this.family.setValue(family); // set family data object be value
}



<div [formGroup]="dataForm">
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="getSelectOption( familyGroup[$event.value] )">
      <mat-option>none</mat-option>
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let family of familyGroup; let i = index"
        value="{{i}}">
            {{ family.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

    //...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="job" #jobMatSelect placeholder="-Select Job-" class="form-control" required>
 <mat-option *ngFor="let item of Jobs" [value]="item.jobId" [disabled]="item.status == false" [ngClass]="{'col-red':item.status == false}"> ({{item.viewValue}})</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

Component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('jobMatSelect') private jobMatSelected: MatSelect;
 this.jobSelected = this.jobMatSelected.triggerValue;
```